# DOM modified by browser at runtime

Tags: javascript, dom

Most browsers modify the structure of the DOM on-the-fly to maintain HTML specification and rules ie. tbody gets inserted when it doesn't exist in a table (as stated in the spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-intable). Similarly adding a DOM element inside a table pushes it before the table.

Is there a consolidated list of known on-the-fly changes that most browsers abide by? I imagine there would be a lot, but I'm looking for a common list. tbody and body (if not existing is added) seem the most obvious. If no list exists then I'm wondering if there's a JS-based library that can be used as a pre-validator for a JSX compiler? This would help detect possibly invalid markup and reduce symptoms related to the DOM being modified.

Comment: This question falls under the "asking for off site resources" close reason.

Comment: The list is exactly on the page that you already linked.

Comment: "*I'm wondering if there's a library that can be used as a validator for JSX*" - yes, you can [use a HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/)